# Python client-server - tell if client offline

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, disconnect

My basic problem is that I am looking for a way for multiple clients to connect to a server over the internet, and for the server to be able to tell if those clients are online or offline.

My current way of doing this is a python socket server, and python clients, which send the server a small message every 2 seconds. The server checks each client to see if it has received such a message in the last 5 seconds, and if not, the client is marked as offline.

However, I feel that is is probably not the best way of doing this, and even if it is, there might be a library that does this for me. I have looked for such a library but have come up empty handed.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this, or a library which can automatically check the status of multiple connected clients?

**Note: by "offline", I mean that the client could be powered off, network connection disconnected or program quit.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not after ping from server to client. I believe that your approach is fine. Very ofther server will not be able to hit client but it works otherway around. You may run out of resources if you have many connected clients.

Also over this established channel you can send other data/metrics and boom monitoring was born ;-) IF you send other data you will probably reliaze you don't need to send data every 2 secs but only if no other data was sent - boom FIX works this way ( and many other messaging protocol)

What you may like is something like kafka that will transport the messages for you there are other messaging protocols too.. and they scale better then if you just connect all client(assuming you have many of them)

Happy messaging

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning i am working a same project and i want to post my approach. 
When a client is connected to my server with `client, address = sock.accept()` we can take his ip with `ip_client = address[0]`. Assuming you have a list with the connected ips you can append the ip with `connected_clients.append(ip_client)`
finally you have a list with the connected ips
make a Thread or inside an infinitive loop write the following code

```
for connected in connected_clients:
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + connected)
    if response == True:
        continue
    else:
        connected_clients.remove(connected)
```

don't forget to the `input os` command on the beginning and you have made a beckon of connected clients